# How to reopen/show Time Tracking panel in JetBrains IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, rubymine

I don't understand how to I close content at panel, but now I see this:

[image]

And now I don't understand how to normal show this panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reopen IDE. Thanks for all.